# capture process output in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy script that recurses through a directory looking for .png files, and invokes [pngquant](http://pngquant.org/) (a command-line utility) on each of. The output of pngquant should be printed on the terminal. The relevant code is:

```
def command = "pngquant -f -ext .png"

root.eachFileRecurse(groovy.io.FileType.FILES) {File file ->

    if (file.name.endsWith('.png')) { 
        println "Compressing file: $file"

        def imgCommand = "$command $file.absolutePath"

        Process pngquantCmd = imgCommand.execute()
        pngquantCmd.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)        
    }
}
```

The script works fine, but once all the files have been processed, it seems that stout is still being redirected, because the command-prompt never appears unless I kill the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Do I need to somehow "undo"

```
pngquantCmd.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

or is there a better way to redirect the output of this process to the console? I guess I could solve this problem simply by adding `System.exit(0)`, but this doesn't seem like the right solution. The problem only occurs on Linux.

Comment: Does `waitForProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )` work any better?

Comment: @tim_yates yes, it works a lot better, thanks very much! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of

```
    pngquantCmd.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

Which will start a couple of threads to read the outputs and plough on regardless of the process' situation, you should try

```
    pngquantCmd.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

Which will redirect the process output and then wait for it to finish before moving on :-)

Comment: Oddly, using `consumeProcessOutput` with StringBuffers followed by `waitForOrKill` is also no good - buffers are sometimes still written after `waitForOrKill`, leading to unpredictable results.  `waitForProcessOutput` is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do

```
Process pngquantCmd = imgCommand.execute();
def output= pngquantCmd.text;
println("Output : " + output);
```

Comment: Does not work for me.