# How do I redirect a process' stdout, stderr and stdin to and from files in Groovy, like in the Bash shell?

Tags: groovy, scripting, groovyshell

I'm porting a Bash shell script to Groovy. Most constructs can easily be converted (e.g. `mkdir "$foo"` to `foo.mkdir()`. However, I'm stumped on this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sleep 60 > /tmp/output.log 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

When running it, let's inspect the file descriptors of `sleep`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$(pgrep sleep)/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Feb 25 13:40 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Feb 25 13:40 1 -> /tmp/output.log
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Feb 25 13:40 2 -> /tmp/output.log
```

Running a process in Groovy can be done this way (according to [this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management)):

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
def log = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/output.log")
def sleep = "sleep 60".execute()
sleep.waitForProcessOutput(log, log)
```

And the file descriptors of `sleep`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$(pgrep sleep)/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Feb 25 13:41 0 -> pipe:[522455]
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Feb 25 13:41 1 -> pipe:[522456]
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Feb 25 13:41 2 -> pipe:[522457]
```

As can be seen, the file descriptors tie to something else (probably the Groovy process). Because this will be used for a long-running process, I'd like to cut out Groovy as a middle man.

So, my question: **how do I redirect a file to `stdin` and `stdout` and `stderr` to files, such that the external process can be detached and Groovy does not need to be running?**

**EDIT:** This question is *not* a duplicate of [capture process output in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579740/capture-process-output-in-groovy), because that question concerns redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to the `stdout` and `stderr` of the Groovy process itself. Which, as can be seen by @tim_yates` answer, is quite a different thing.

Comment: have you checked http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management ?

Comment: Yes, I even linked to it in my question.

Comment: You can pass writers to the method, so just open a writer to the file, and pass that in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput()` can solve this problem [since Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File)). And because it's standard Java, it can also be used in Groovy.

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
def sleep = new ProcessBuilder('sleep', '60')
                    .redirectOutput(new File('/tmp/output.log'))
                    .redirectErrorStream(true)
                    .redirectInput(new File('/dev/null'))
                    .start();
```

The result:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$(pgrep sleep)/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Feb 26 11:44 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Feb 26 11:44 1 -> /tmp/output.log
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Feb 26 11:44 2 -> /tmp/output.log
```

`ProcessBuilder.start()` returns a `java.lang.Process`, which is decorated by Groovy. Methods such as `waitForOrKill` will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just leverage the shell? Let it do what it was designed to do. To wit:

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
def sleep = (["sh", "-c", "sleep 60 > /tmp/output.log 2>&1 < /dev/null"] as String[]).execute()
```

If you need to specify the output file programmatically, then just use a GString:

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
def outfile = "/tmp/output.log"
String[] sleepCmd = ["sh", "-c", "sleep 60 > ${outfile} 2>&1 < /dev/null"]
def sleep = sleepCmd.execute()
```

(Edited both examples to use `String[]` rather than `String`)

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work - `sleep` doesn't run. Adding the line `sleep.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)`, the terminal shows `60: 1: 60: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`.

Comment: Rats. Forgot that it's using StringTokenizer naively under the hood. Will fix. Please note that @spaceknarf 's self-solution is far superior to this one in any case.