# Write file from Groovy using unix shell

Tags: groovy

I want to write file from groovy.
I tried execute shell, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
this_job_id = 43294;
"echo THIS_JOB_ID=${this_job_id.toString()} > build_groovy.properties".execute()
```

For some reason build_groovy.properties doesn't create

Comment: This is more of a groovy question than a shell question: It depends on the details of exactly how String.execute() works there.

Comment: ...and, of course, the details of string interpolation in Groovy matter too: If your `${}` expression wasn't replaced, this will be a parse error at the shell.

Comment: Proving that this is a Groovy problem, not a shell problem, is trivial: Run `echo THIS_JOB_ID=43294 > build_groovy.properties`, and you'll see your file is correctly created; thus, the issue is on the Groovy side, not the shell side, so your question should be tagged `groovy`, not `shell`.

Comment: Why use `echo`? Spawning a process to write to a file seems excessive. Groovy can write to files you know?

Comment: If you have to use the shell, then this feels like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717454/how-do-i-redirect-a-process-stdout-stderr-and-stdin-to-and-from-files-in-groov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a file from groovy

```
new File('build_groovy.properties').text = "THIS_JOB_ID=$this_job_id"
```